# How to avoid redefining error when overriding property via typescript decorators

Tags: typescript, prototype, typescript-decorator, propertydescriptor

I use object-oriented style when defining data for my interface. Since Vue 3 provided Composition API, simply assigning instances of my classes to properties of `data` object inside component is some sort of deprecated way only for backward compatibility.

I'm trying to write decorators for wrap properties of class instances in `ref` and `reactive`. It looks like this (*naming only for example purposes)*:

```ts
@UseVueReactivity
class X {
  @Ref
  a = 10

  @Reactive
  b = { foo: 'bar' }

  @ShallowReactive
  c = { a: { deepA: 'deepAValue' } }

  // ... and so on
}
```

The implementation is simple: decorators like `@Ref`, `@Reactive` just add keys to array, that stored in class prototype by specific `symbol` key. Values of that keys should be wrapped by pair of accessors in `@UseVueReactivity`, just like in example below (some type annotations omitted for better readability).

```ts
const refKeysSymbol = Symbol('Ref keys symbol')
const reactiveKeysSymbol = Symbol('Reactive keys symbol')
// ... and so on

const Ref = (target, key) => {
  // Skipping part, when we assure that array by symbol key exists
  target[refKeysSymbol].push(key)
}

const UseVueReactivity = <T extends Function>(Original: T): T => {
  return class extends Original {
    constructor (...args) {
      super(...args)
    }

    const refPropKeys = Extendable.prototype[refKeysSymbol] as string[] ?? []
    
    for (const key of refPropKeys) {
      const refPropKey = `Ref.${key}` // Key for result of ref()

      Reflect.defineProperty(this, refPropKey, {
        value: ref(this[key]) // Trying to set initial value, the first part of question
      })

      Reflect.defineProperty(this, key, {
        get () {
          return this[refPropKey].value
        },
        set (v) {
          this[refPropKey].value = v
        },
        configurable: true
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Now, example for the question, where error from title occures.
Suppose we have class `A` and `B`, that extends `A`

```ts
@UseVueReactivity
class A {
  @Ref
  foo = 10
}

@UseVueReactivity
class B extends A {
  @Ref
  bar = 20
}

const a = new A()
const b = new B()
```

If we log `a` in Chrome Devtools we will see something like this:

```
{
  Ref.foo: RefImpl { ... }
  get foo: f get()
  set foo: f set(v)
  ...
}
```

Property value will remain: `a.foo = 10`. But if we log `b` and will try to change its `bar` value, we will receive `undefined` as start value for `b.bar` and consequently `NaN` as a result of, for example, `b.bar++`.

If we remove `configurable: true`, in `@UseVueReactivity` we will get a

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: bar
  at B.<instance_members_initializer>
  ...
```

I assume that even if I use `Reflect.defineProperty` to define accessors for `b.bar`, the code `@Ref bar = 20` or even `@Ref bar` in `B` class definition will *redefine* my accessors, that is why error is throws if I leave configurable flag with `false`. But I don't want class to overwrite a overrided property.

My questions are: What am I doing wrong in redefinition properties when decorating already decorated class and what am I supposed to do, to fix this?

May be I miss some details about prototype extending in JS, but I can't take it all together. I appreciate if you point on specs or MDN, where that sort of details mentioned.

Thank you.